# Unwanted double assignment on array function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function myFunction()
{     
    var Arr2
    if(Arr1!=null)
    {
        Arr2=Arr1
        console.log("Arr2 before for: "+Arr2)
        console.log("Arr1 before for: "+Arr1)
    }               
    for(var index=-1+Arr2.length;index>=0;index--)
    {
        if(Arr2[index]=="to_delete")
        {
            Arr2.splice(index,1)
        }
    }
    console.log("Arr1 after for: "+Arr1)
    console.log("Arr2 after for: "+Arr2)
}
```

I create Arr2 in a function, Arr2=Arr1, the problem is that Arr1 is also being spliced during for, and from these last two console.logs i am informed that these 2 arrays are the same. (I only want to change Arr2)

Comment: When you say `Arr2=Arr1`, you're basically making `Arr2` another name for `Arr1`. You need to make a copy of `Arr1` instead.

Comment: got to make `Arr2 = [...Arr1]`

Comment: ES6 is not yet fully supported and the OP does not mention anything about being able to use ES6 syntax.

Comment: @Enzey I just wanted to give another perspective to those reading this question. At the end of the day if you are in to JS you are in to ES6 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `Arr2 = Arr1`, you're just copying the reference to that array, you're not making a copy of the array itself. So both `Arr1` and `Arr2` will now refer to the same array.

Try changing

```
Arr2=Arr1
```

to

```
Arr2 = Arr1.slice()
```

which should copy all of the elements in `Arr1` to the new `Arr2`. Check out [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use filter Array method like this :

```
var arr2 = arr1.filter(x => x!="to_delete");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a reference to Arr1, not a new object. 
Think of it this way:
[image]

Think of it this way: when you initialise Arr1, you're allocating it to a piece of memory on the heap. This reference is then given an address.

The assignment `var Arr2 = Arr1` equals the same as saying, Arr2 is the same as Arr1 **by reference**. Which means it points to the same memory address.

If you want to make a copy of an object, a.k.a. pass it **by value**, you should use one of the following methods.

```
var Arr2 = Arr1.slice(0);
```

Keep in mind however that if your array contains objects, these are cloned by reference with this method. Example:

```
var Arr1 = [{a: 1, b: 2, c:3}, {d: 4, e: 5, f: 6}]
var Arr2 = Arr1.slice(0)
Arr1[0].a = 2;
console.log(Arr2[0].a) // this will output 2
```

If you want to easily do a deep clone without having to write the code to pass the object references by value, you can use something like **lodash** or just:

```
var Arr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Arr1));
```

Which also works.